# Azure and GitHub Actions: runtime-platform error while attempting to deploy container to Azure container apps

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, github-actions, jib

I have a simple spring boot API that I'm trying to get Deployed via CI/CD using GitHub Actions on Azure. I'm using Azure container apps todo so.

However when I commit a change to my main branch, everything goes ok until it tries to deploy the image (I think). I' constantly getting hit with a Runtime-platform error. I've attempted (As seen below) to specify the runtime platform in the yaml file but to no luck.

If anyone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

```yaml
name: Trigger auto deployment for search-service-production

# When this action will be executed
on:
  # Automatically trigger it when detected changes in repo
  push:
    branches: 
      [ main ]
    paths:
    - '**'
    - '.github/workflows/search-service-production-AutoDeployTrigger-b9ef6edb-c114-41e7-be4e-b7087d14ea7f.yml'

  # Allow manually trigger 
  workflow_dispatch:
      
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout to the branch
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Azure Login
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.SEARCHSERVICEPRODUCTION_AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          cache: 'gradle'

      - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Build and Push ACR Image
        env:
          ACR_REGISTRY: mytest.azurecr.io  # Replace with your ACR login server
          ACR_REPOSITORY: tfs-search-service  # Replace with the desired ACR repository
          ACR_IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          ./gradlew jib -Djib.to.auth.username=${{ secrets.SEARCHSERVICEPRODUCTION_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}\
            -Djib.to.auth.password=${{ secrets.SEARCHSERVICEPRODUCTION_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }} \
            -Djib.to.image=mytest.azurecr.io/tfs-search-service:${{ github.sha }}

      - name: Build and Deploy to Azure Container Apps
        uses: azure/container-apps-deploy-action@v1
        with:
          appSourcePath: ${{ github.workspace }} 
          registryUrl: mytest.azurecr.io
          registryUsername: ${{ secrets.SEARCHSERVICEPRODUCTION_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          registryPassword: ${{ secrets.SEARCHSERVICEPRODUCTION_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
          containerAppName: search-service-production
          resourceGroup: mytest-production
          runtime-platform: linux/amd64
          imageToDeploy: mytest.azurecr.io/search-service-production:${{ github.sha }}
```

When I commit a change to main, the git action runs as expected but I'm seeing this error:

```
Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/oryx/cli:builder-debian-buster-20230208.1' locally
builder-debian-buster-20230208.1: Pulling from oryx/cli
d42a0fb443d7: Pulling fs layer
f390d41539fb: Pulling fs layer
103b21370b9f: Pulling fs layer
fddd5b6145de: Pulling fs layer
16dfd13d3a05: Pulling fs layer
27df7571ea34: Pulling fs layer
99ad81e721c7: Pulling fs layer
4136820462f5: Pulling fs layer
6c84a682b950: Pulling fs layer
6e38c43918bc: Pulling fs layer
9beff6fb6da7: Pulling fs layer
61093d47cb77: Pulling fs layer
205ffbb9f89d: Pulling fs layer
fddd5b6145de: Waiting
16dfd13d3a05: Waiting
6e38c43918bc: Waiting
27df7571ea34: Waiting
99ad81e721c7: Waiting
9beff6fb6da7: Waiting
61093d47cb77: Waiting
205ffbb9f89d: Waiting
4136820462f5: Waiting
f390d41539fb: Download complete
103b21370b9f: Verifying Checksum
103b21370b9f: Download complete
16dfd13d3a05: Verifying Checksum
16dfd13d3a05: Download complete
d42a0fb443d7: Verifying Checksum
d42a0fb443d7: Download complete
27df7571ea34: Verifying Checksum
27df7571ea34: Download complete
99ad81e721c7: Verifying Checksum
99ad81e721c7: Download complete
fddd5b6145de: Verifying Checksum
fddd5b6145de: Download complete
6e38c43918bc: Verifying Checksum
6e38c43918bc: Download complete
6c84a682b950: Verifying Checksum
6c84a682b950: Download complete
9beff6fb6da7: Verifying Checksum
9beff6fb6da7: Download complete
4136820462f5: Verifying Checksum
4136820462f5: Download complete
d42a0fb443d7: Pull complete
205ffbb9f89d: Verifying Checksum
205ffbb9f89d: Download complete
f390d41539fb: Pull complete
61093d47cb77: Verifying Checksum
61093d47cb77: Download complete
103b21370b9f: Pull complete
fddd5b6145de: Pull complete
16dfd13d3a05: Pull complete
27df7571ea34: Pull complete
99ad81e721c7: Pull complete
4136820462f5: Pull complete
6c84a682b950: Pull complete
6e38c43918bc: Pull complete
9beff6fb6da7: Pull complete
61093d47cb77: Pull complete
205ffbb9f89d: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2d5eaa1e75ef73b5bf461a573d8fdf40cb7bc1596be2f0b044f5eb0231a8e94c
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/oryx/cli:builder-debian-buster-20230208.1
Error: Either the value provided to the --runtime-platform argument is empty, or the platform discovered by Oryx does not have any available or supported runtime images. Please view the following document for more information on runtimes supported by Oryx: https://aka.ms/oryx-runtime-images
```

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Either the value provided to the --runtime-platform argument is empty, or the platform discovered by Oryx does not have any available or supported runtime images.

The error seems to be due to the provided runtime platform `linux/amd64` in the YAML file and also in case of application expecting a different runtime platform.

- Ensure the `linux/amd64` platform is valid and supported.
- Check by removing the `runtime-platform` parameter from the workflow if you are not sure about the runtime platform. This allows Container Apps to detect the runtime platform required by the application automatically which will work if the issue was related to compatibility.

```yaml
appSourcePath: ${{ github.workspace }} 
registryUrl: <acrname>.azurecr.io
registryUsername: ${{ secrets.SEARCHSERVICEPRODUCTION_REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
registryPassword: ${{ secrets.SEARCHSERVICEPRODUCTION_REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
containerAppName: <container_app_name>
resourceGroup: <resource_group_name>
imageToDeploy: <acrname.azurecr.io/search-service-production:${{ github.sha }}
```

- Re-check and validate the whole configuration to make sure everything configured properly.
- Check the logs of the deployment for detailed information about the errors in Logs/Logstream in the left pane.

[image]